# How to create if conditional inside a stored procedure postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

In my procedure I need to create if condition. I googled for that information and created that statement, but when I'm trying to execute that postgres throws "syntax error near if" error. May you help me, because I spent four hours trying to fix that error?

Here is code of procedure I'm trying to execute.

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE addLocomotive(addModel varchar(255),addNumber varchar(255), addFuelpriceper100km int,addYearofproduction int)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
if 1>0 then
  select 1;
else
  select 0;
END if;
--insert into locomotives(model,number,fuelpriceper100km,yearOfProduction) values(addModel,addNumber,addFuelPriceper100km,addYearOfProduction);
$$;
```

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL, you have to use PL/pgSQL if you need procedural code

Comment: You can also use a CASE, and that can be used inside the INSERT statement as well